# "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to fix this and I don't know how... When I click on the first button the second doesn't appear. It raises this exception:

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

I tried everything but I don't know what to do anymore.

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test\main.py", line 26, in <lambda>
    boutonAlphabetMaj.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: boutonAlphabetMaj.config(fg='#3f3f3f', bg='#383838'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time
import os

# Root
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(1920, 1080)
root.maxsize(1920, 1080)
# Frame + Canvas
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, borderwidth=0)
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, height=1080, width=1920, borderwidth=0, bg="#383838")
frame.grid()
canvas.grid()
# Fonctions
def alphabet() :
    canvas.delete("boutonAlphabet")
    # Bouton Alphabet Majuscule
    pathAlphabetMaj = os.path.join("test/alphabetMaj.png")
    pictureAlphabetMaj = Image.open(pathAlphabetMaj)
    picAlphabetMaj = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pictureAlphabetMaj)
    boutonAlphabetMaj = tk.Button(canvas, image=picAlphabetMaj, borderwidth=0, bg="#383838", activebackground="#4a4a4a", cursor="hand2")
    picAlphabetMaj.pictureAlphabetMaj = pictureAlphabetMaj
    boutonAlphabetMaj.bind("<Enter>", lambda e: boutonAlphabetMaj.config(fg='#383838', bg='#3f3f3f'))
    boutonAlphabetMaj.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: boutonAlphabetMaj.config(fg='#3f3f3f', bg='#383838'))
    canvas.create_window(200, 500, window=boutonAlphabetMaj, tags=("boutonAlphabetMaj"))

# Titre
canvas.create_text(960, 50, text="APPRENDRE LE FRANÇAIS", font=("",50), fill="white")
# Bouton Alphabet
pathAlphabet = os.path.join("test/alphabet.png")
pictureAlphabet = Image.open(pathAlphabet)
picAlphabet = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pictureAlphabet)
boutonAlphabet = tk.Button(canvas, image=picAlphabet, borderwidth=0, bg="#383838", activebackground="#4a4a4a", command=lambda: alphabet(), cursor="hand2")
picAlphabet.pictureAlphabet = pictureAlphabet
boutonAlphabet.bind("<Enter>", lambda e: boutonAlphabet.config(fg='#383838', bg='#3f3f3f'))
boutonAlphabet.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: boutonAlphabet.config(fg='#3f3f3f', bg='#383838'))
canvas.create_window(200, 250, window=boutonAlphabet, tags=("boutonAlphabet"))

# loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: shorter: `command=alphabet` without `lambda` and without `()`

Comment: it can be common problem with bug in `ImagePhoto` which removes image when it is assigned to local variable in function. You have to assing it to global variable or to class. It seems you try to resolve this problem but you used wrong variables. You assign `Image.open()` to `PhotoImage` but you should assign `PhotoImage` to button `boutonAlphabetMaj`. Maybe if you would have shorter names - ie. `picture`, `pic`, `button` - or use names with `_` -  oe. then you would see this mistake

Comment: Okk, so the the problem was the local variable in the function thanks a lot. Any reason why I should use "command=alphabet" instead of lambda ? Wha'ts the difference ? Is it just shorter ? Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: `command=` expects only function's name without `()` and arguments - and using only name `command=alphabet` is standard method (not only in Tkinter but also in PyQt, wxPython, etc. and also in other languages -ie. JavaScript). We use `lambda` only when we have to assign function with arguments `command=lambda: alphabet(arguments)`

Comment: Oh okk ! I didn't know that, I saw your anwser it's working ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have common problem with `bug` in `ImagePhoto` which removes image when it is assigned to local variable in function. You have to assign it to global variable or to class.

It seems you try to resolve this problem but you use wrong variables.

You assign `Image.open()` to `PhotoImage` .

```
    picAlphabetMaj.pictureAlphabetMaj = pictureAlphabetMaj
```

but you should assign `PhotoImage` to button `boutonAlphabetMaj`

```
    boutonAlphabetMaj.pictureAlphabetMaj = picAlphabetMaj
```